# ¿Por qué algunas etiquetas no se muestran con el logo de la empresa, como sí pasa en SO?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, stackexchange

Algunas etiquetas en Stack Overflow están patrocinados (o al menos así las llamo yo, pero no sé si es el termino mas correcto). La cuestión es que en Stack Overflow en español no se muestran igual que en otros lugares de la red.

Por ejemplo tenemos los siguientes:

- [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [go](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)
- [google-chrome](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

Que son como se muestran es SO en español.

Y a continuación es cómo se muestran en SO en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es esto un bug? Aunque me inclino a pensar que sea  por estar en beta, lo que haga que se muestren de la forma mencionada.

Comment: no se si sera casualidad pero todos los que he visto de esta manera son relacionados de alguna manera con Google por ejemplo el de youtube-api, por eso no he puesto otros Saludos

Comment: En realidad ninguna etiqueta patrocinada se muestra en el sitio en [español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni en [portugués](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni [ruso](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni [japonés](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Answer (score 9):

En realidad ninguna etiqueta patrocinada se muestra en el sitio en [español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni en [portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni [ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags), ni [japonés](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Esto se debe a que las empresas que patrocinan esas etiquetas han **hecho contratos con Stack Overflow** para poner sus íconos al costado. Es de suponer que estos contratos están hechos específicamente para Stack Overflow en inglés y por el momento al parecer no se está extendiendo a ninguna de las traducciones.